# Can facebook/twitter user register to wordpress quickly?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, plugins, twitter

Is there any plungins or api(tutorial) can make user register to each wordpress and facebook/twitter quickly? just a confirm bottom that can write all the register users information into wordpress from facebook/twitter? And write all the register users information into facebook/twitter from wordpress? 
Thanks.

Comment: I think you mean "confirm button"?

Comment: @Nathan, yes, my spelling mistakes ,some button can connect both database and share each register user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THe best, most comprehensive solution I've found is Janrain RPX Engage

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rpx/

There is also 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-facebook-connect/ 
and
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-twitter-connect/

Comment: thanks, I have down the rpx, after active, I can not see any setting page in the admin-panel, how to setup it?

Comment: You need an account with them and the free account is pretty good out of the box. The settings are in your account. You can find documentation here: https://rpxnow.com/docs